# Why React JS Link is rendering variable as a String within URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React Link to add 'Edit Student' page link in my table. However, without any apparent errors, the variable is not getting passed along the URL. Instead, the URL is being rendered as a complete string. I am currently learning React JS. I haven't worked with JavaScript much as I usually code back-end, so, I have no idea how to troubleshoot this one. I have tried searching everywhere but can't find the solution.

My code from Student.js (Complete code in Reference below):

```
              <Link
                to={"edit-student/$id{item.id}"}
                className="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                Edit
              </Link>
```

URL that is supposed to get rendered: `http://localhost:3000/edit-student/1`

URL that is being rendered: `http://localhost:3000/edit-student/$id%7Bitem.id%7D`

For Reference:

App.js Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Student from "./pages/Student";
import Addstudent from "./pages/Addstudent";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Student} />
        <Route path="/add-student" component={Addstudent} />
        <Route path="/edit-student/:id" component={Addstudent} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Student.js Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class Student extends Component {
  state = {
    students: [],
    loading: true,
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/students");
    if (res.data.status === 200) {
      this.setState({
        students: res.data.students,
        loading: false,
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    var student_HTMLTABLE = "";
    if (this.state.loading) {
      student_HTMLTABLE = (
        <tr>
          <td colSpan="7">
            <h2>Loading...</h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    } else {
      student_HTMLTABLE = this.state.students.map((item) => {
        return (
          <tr key={item.id}>
            <td>{item.id}</td>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td>{item.course}</td>
            <td>{item.email}</td>
            <td>{item.phone}</td>
            <td>
              <Link
                to={"edit-student/$id{item.id}"}
                className="btn btn-success btn-sm"
              >
                Edit
              </Link>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button">
                Delete
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      });
    }
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-header">
                <h4>
                  Student Data
                  <Link
                    to="add-student"
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-end"
                  >
                    Add Student
                  </Link>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div className="card-body">
                <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Course</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                      <th>Phone</th>
                      <th>Edit</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{student_HTMLTABLE}</tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Student;
```

My Dependencies in Package.json

```
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update like this by using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
to={`edit-student/${item.id}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly passing in `item.id` in the string, not as a variable but just a string. It is getting encoded into the text you see.

You probably need :

```
{"edit-student/" + item.id }
```